# Make tkinter label refresh at set time intervals

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a window and list. I want to output the numbers and make them disappear at intervals of one second.

```
list1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}

def Display_num():

    for i in range(20):

    display=tkinter.Label(window, text=list1[i],width=25, height=3,fg="black",relief="solid")

    display.pack()

    display.after(1000,display.destroy)
```

But when I run this program, the labels are printed and disappear at the same time. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Your `for` loop runs in a matter of milliseconds, as there are no particularly lengthy operations within it.  So you create all 20 Labels essentially at once, then about a second later all of the `.after()`s fire off one after another.  You can't do this with a loop - create a single Label, its `.after()` will be a function (perhaps `Display_num()` itself) that will create the next Label (or better yet, just change the text of the existing label.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

def loop(lbl, ls, flash: bool = False):
    if ls:
        if not flash:
            val, *ls = ls

            lbl.config(text=val)

            lbl.after(1000, loop, lbl, ls, not flash)

        else:
            lbl.config(text=" ")

            lbl.after(250, loop, lbl, ls, not flash)
        
    else:
        lbl.config(text="Fin")

        

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Default")

label.pack()

loop(label, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

root.mainloop()
```

Updates the label each second while the list is not empty. Once the list is empty then it sets the label text to `fin`.

### Edit

Added a short 'flash' between numbers as per comment request.

Comment: Thank you!! Sorry, But I have one more question. How can I add empty label between the numbers?? empty label is printed for really short time

Comment: What do you mean a label between the numbers? @권준하

Comment: Sorry about my poor english. When I run this program, the numbers are changed consecutively. It'll be great if the numbers are printed like --> '1' appears, and it is gone for  short time and '2' appears and......

Comment: Thank you so much!! Since I was new to tkinter, I struggled with it for a week T.T